# Why do certain parameter types cause ambiguous routing in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Suppose I have a *very* simple routing table, like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("root", "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

And within my `HomeController`, I have two methods called `Index`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { service = "hard-coded string" });
}

[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Index(string a)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { a });
}
```

If I run this application, routing occurs as I would expect: if I omit the `a` parameter from the query string, my request gets routed to the first method, and if I include it, the request is routed to the second method.

*However*, if I change the type of `a` to a more complex type, such as `string[]`, then when I make a request on the default route, I get the following error (regardless of whether I specified the query parameter):

```
{
  Message: "An error has occurred."
  ExceptionMessage: "Multiple actions were found that match the request: Index on type SurveysApi.v1.Web.Controllers.HomeController Index on type SurveysApi.v1.Web.Controllers.HomeController"
  ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
  StackTrace: " at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

The error remains if even if I specify `FromUri` or `ModelBinder` attributes on the parameter.

Why does this error occur for complex types, and is there any way to avoid it, short of specifying a simple type in the argument list and performing the necessary conversions in the controller method?

Comment: this seems like it might be a serialization issue, I don't know what encoding you are using but when a json object is passed attributes that are null are simply omitted from the serialization.  this would cause the default url and a url that the object such as a null array to have the same URL in a get request, so yes there would be two actions that fit that url

Answer (score 1):

Method overloading doesn't seem to play well with Web API. What I suggest you use instead is attribute routing.

Enable it in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

An example Controller would be:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("home/id/{Id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(int Id)
    {
        return "id";
    }

    [Route("home/string/{str}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string str)
    {
        return "string";
   }
}
```

Method names are the same, but routes are the key factor. Another way you could do this is using the ActionName attribute:

An example Controller would be:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("GetById")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "id";
    }

    [ActionName("GetByGUID")]
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        return "guid";
    }
}
```

Routes would be something like:

```
//Matches /api/Home/7
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultDigitApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetById" },
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be digits
);

//Matches /api/Home/CD73FAD2-E226-4715-B6FA-14EDF0764162
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultGuidApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetByGUID" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b" } // id must be guid
);
```

Hope this helps at least a bit.